# Simplificar fracciones

Tags: python

Intento hacer una clase 'Fraccion' la cual contenga un metodo que me simplifique la fraccion ingresada, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
class fracciones():
    def funcion(self,numerador, denominador):
        self.numerador=numerador
        self.denominador=denominador
        self.ti=2
        self.r_num = float(self.numerador)/self.ti
        self.r_den = float(self.denominador)/self.ti
        return self.r_num,self.r_den
    def comprobante(self):
        if(self.r_num.is_integer() and self.r_den.is_integer()):
           print(self.r_num,"/",self.r_den)
           return self.funcion(self.r_num,self.r_den)
        else:        
           if(self.ti == self.numerador or self.ti == self.denominador or self.r_num <= 1 or self.r_den <= 1):
            return print("La máxima expresión: ", self.numerador,"/",self.denominador)
           else:
               self.ti += 1
               return self.funcion(self.numerador, self.denominador)

p=fracciones()
fr=p.funcion(18,9)
print(p.comprobante())
```

Aun no entiendo que es lo que me esta quedadon malo, como tal no la simplifica solo hace lo de la primera funcion y lo devuelve:

```
(9.0, 4.5)
```

Comment: Bueno, yo la veo correcta... el hecho es que 45 / 2 da 22.5, y 22.5 no es un entero así que ya no entra a tu primer if... luego pusiste un else y ese else tiene un else? Cuando va a entrar a tu segundo else? Revisa la indentación de tu código

Comment: perdon ya lo corregi, es que a la hora de poner el codigo aqui todo aperecia muy apretado y no entendia muy bien donde iba cada cosa pero ya lo puse bien

Comment: Para que sean fracciones de verdad deberías usar `int` y no `float` para representar numerador y denominador. Ver una fracción 5.0 / 1.0 me produce angustia mental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaba viendo tu código y creo que se puede optimizar. En este caso la diferencia inicial es que se crea Fraccion asignando los valores. Podría utilizarse la class antes de ser simplificada, con los valores iniciales asignados y puede imprimirse después cuando ya fue simplificada.

Se inicia instanciando class Fraccion y dándole valor de numerador y denominador.

Después solo queda que simplificar() se encargue de la simplificación.

```
class Fraccion:
    def __init__(self, numerador, denominador):
        self.numerador = numerador
        self.denominador = denominador

    def simplificar(self):
        for i in range(2, self.numerador):
            if self.numerador % i == 0 and self.denominador % i == 0:
                self.numerador = self.numerador // i
                self.denominador = self.denominador // i
        return self.numerador, self.denominador

    def mostrarValores(self):
        print(self.numerador, "/", self.denominador)



# instanciamos la class Fraccion
fraccion1= Fraccion(10, 2)
# llamamos al metodo mostrarValores
fraccion1.mostrarValores()

10 / 2
```

Ahora fraccion1 tiene los valores de la Fraccion para poder ser utilizados aun sin simplificar.

```
# llamamos al método simplificar
fraccion1.simplificar()
# llamamos al método mostrarValores
fraccion1.mostrarValores()
```

Lo que va a imprimir es la fracción simplificada de la siguiente manera:

```
5 / 1
```

Espero que sea de ayuda y permita mejorar tu proyecto. Saludos.

Comment: deberías usar la doble barra `//`

Comment: Amigo es usted un sol, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Christian Ahora le adicione las doble barra. Gracias por el detalle!

Answer (score 1):

una humilde contribución, espero no estar equivocado, pero agradeceré si lo estoy y me lo hacen notar. A la solución dada por el usuario anterior (AleBuo) para el método "simplificar" creo que se le debe sumar uno al numerador para que funcione en todos los casos.

Quedaría así:

```
def simplificar(self):
        for i in range(2, self.numerador + 1):
            if self.numerador % i == 0 and self.denominador % i == 0:
                self.numerador = self.numerador // i
                self.denominador = self.denominador // i
        return self.numerador, self.denominador
```

al sumar "+ 1" al numerador te aseguras que al simplificar fracciones como "3/6" dé la respuesta correcta. Si no te seguiría devolviendo "3/6".